# Catalog Price Rule in Percentage in group Product

Tags: magento2, catalog-rules

i want to add percentage in magneto2 catalog rule on list page show price i want to show percentage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new catalog price rule at

> Admin > Marketing > Promotions > Catalog Price Rules

and select "Adjust final price to this percentage" or "Apply as percentage of Original"

[image]

Provide more details if this is not what you are looking for.